# Cool fired energy ball for a game. How to achieve?

Tags: andengine, game-engine

I wanna to achieve an effect like a fired blue ball (ball with energy) before to shoot it on the sky. I thought to use some particle systems but a friend of mine said that it's very expensive for the memory to use particle system. Is there a different way to achieve this ? Where can I find some examples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particle Systems are probably the best way and can achieve some really nice looking effects.

It depends how optimized your particle system is, but my game used a ton and it ran fast and smooth (this was with OpenGL ES).

Generally they're fine if you keep the max particles as low as possible (whilst still looking good).

Thanks to an open source engine (cocos2d iphone) I also got all my particle systems to render in the same OpenGL call.